# Google Analytics traffic sources shows 538 visits with 0 pages / visit

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics

I'm looking at my Google Analytic traffic sources report, along with the 'landing page' secondary dimension.

Under the source '(direct)/(none)' there's a landing page called '(not set)' which has 538 visits and 0 pages / visit, and 00:00:00 visit duration. How could this possibly be?

Answer (score 1):

This is rather common and most times it happens if people are bouncing of your site quickly.

Take a look at your bounce rate and if that's high it means people are quickly leaving your site before Google Analytics updates the time on site meaning they its 0 since they added it as a direct bounce.

Comment: But how can it not even register as a page view? Even a bounce is a page view, if the visitor was there long enough to load google analytics then they definitely viewed the page.